# How to use more than 1 condition in one "if" function?

Tags: c

I want to change the value of `_"ans"_` in every condition of this script:

```
main(){
    char in;
    int  ans=0;
    printf ("Enter character");
    scanf ("%c",&in);
    if (in == '+' && in == '/' && in == '*' && in == '-'){
        ans=10;
    }
}
```

How do I do that?

Comment: You want to replace `&&` with `||`.

Comment: The next class will teach you with the `||` (or) operator.

Comment: `if` is not a function. It is a conditional statement. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_(computer_programming)#If%E2%80%93then(%E2%80%93else)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`if (A && B)…` does not mean:

- do this if A is true, and
- do this if B is true.

It means:

- do this if A is true and B is true.

To make a condition so the `if` is triggered if A is true and is triggered if B is true, you use `A || B`. This means:

- do this if A is true or B is true.

Answer (score 1):

In the end, you'll probably want a switch case.

```
main()
{
        char in;
        int  ans=10;
        printf ("Enter character");
        scanf ("%c",&in);
        switch(in){
           case '+':
              ans=ans+10;
              break;
           case '-':
              ans=ans-10;
              break;
           case '/':
              ans=ans/10;
              break;
           case '*':
              ans=ans*10;
              break;

        }
}
```

Further steps in the exercise are probably going to be to parse the input factors to the calculations as well, rather than just multiplying static ans with 10.